# Question about ordered pairs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

While reading through a book on discrete mathematics, it never occured to me to think of a 1-tuple. That is, an ordered singleton (or ordered unit set). Now, do such sets exist? Using the Kuratowski Definition, the ordered singleton (a) is equal to {{a}}. But as so is the ordered pair (a,a) equal to {{a}}. So is (a,a) = (a)? Could someone point out where my logic is flawed, please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be consistent with my current knowledge. The ordered pair (a,b) is {{a},{a,b}}. And the ordered pair (a,a) is {{a},{a,a}} which is {{a},{a}} and which is {{a}}.

Comment: @Camelot823 "Using the Kuratowski Definition, the ordered singleton (a) is equal to {{a}}." - According to whom?

Comment: Umm.. according to Kuratowski? Isn't (a) = {{a}}? If, not, what is it defined to be?

Comment: Please use MathJax. It isn't always easy to read ASCII math. A tutorial is [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/742).

Answer (score 1):

The Kuratowski definition is used for **ordered pairs**, so $(a)$ is not defined as $\{\{a\}\}$.

$1$-tuples are not defined, since they carry the same amount of information as a single element. The point of defining tuples was to introduce an order into the set. When the set consists of a single element, such orders are useless.

Finally, it is true that $(a,a)=\{\{a\}\}$, which is yet another reason why one wouldn't want to define $1$-tuple the way you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Having defined ordered pairs (e.g., using the Kuratowski definition $(x, y) = \{\{x\}, \{x, y\}\}$), we define functional relations (as certain sets of ordered pairs) and then define $n$-tuples as functions whose domain is $\{1, \ldots, n\}$. $1$-tuples then show up as functions with domain $\{1\}$, but the notation $(a)$ for the $1$-tuple $\{(1, a)\}$ is never used in practice in my experience.

As suggested in my comment below, you can use angle brackets as a (reasonably standard) substitute for round brackets so that you can write $\langle a \rangle$ to make it clear that that your mean the $1$-tuple with one element $a$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! But what about those times when we actually need to use (a)? For example, consider the cartesian product of the family indexed by a singleton. Do we just replace {a} instead?

Comment: The $1$-tuple is $\{(1, a)\}$. Brackets are an overloaded notation: if there are no commas inside, then they are just the usual brackets we use for grouping expressions in algebra. If it is important to you to have a notation for $1$-tuples, then I suggest you use different brackets: $\langle a \rangle$, $\langle a, b \rangle$ etc.